# Fetching secrets from vault using gitlab

Tags: gitlab-ci, jq, cicd, vault

I am trying to integrate vault with gitlab and fetch secrets from vault using jwt authentication. I am able to retrieve the vault token using command.

```
export VAULT_TOKEN = $(curl \
    --request POST \
    --data '{"jwt": "your_jwt", "role": "demo"}' \
    http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/jwt/login | jq -r .auth.client_token)
```

Now I am trying to consume this token to fetch the secret.

```
list_secrets=$(curl -k --header "X-Vault-Token:${VAULT_TOKEN} <vaulturl>)
```

I am getting an HTML page in the list_secrets but unable to see the actual secrets in the tags of html code.

on top of this, I am trying to fetch individual secret using below command.

```
Secret_1=$(echo ${list_secrets} | jq -r .data.data'."dbname.password"')
echo $Secret_1
```

This echo command gives me error invalid numeric literal at column 1 line 10

Can someone guide me please how can I fetch the secret.

Comment: "I am getting an HTML page in the list_secrets" means your API endpoint is wrong, but you also did not share it in the question, so we cannot assist further without an update.

Comment: what shud be the output of the api end point ? json because I am doing curl command...and curl will return a html page @Matt

Comment: There are several typos in your scripts which may cause similar issues: `export VAULT_TOKEN = $(…` has too many whitespaces; `list_secrets=$(` has no `)`; `echi` is not spelled correctly; …